# Set the correct path to a file

Tags: c

Im trying to compile the code below, it is a code free available and Im trying to understand it. And I was trying to test it but Im getting an issue. I got a message error "Error opening file filename.txt. Error 2".

I think that should be because the file is not located in the appropriated folder. I have the file in the desktop, do you know how to set the path to the file in c as th the desktop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define MD5LEN  16

DWORD main()
{
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    BYTE rgbFile[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD cbRead = 0;
    BYTE rgbHash[MD5LEN];
    DWORD cbHash = 0;
    CHAR rgbDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    LPCSTR filename = "filename.txt";
    // Logic to check usage goes here.

    hFile = CreateFile(filename,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        NULL);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("Error opening file %s\nError: %d\n", filename,
            dwStatus);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    // Get handle to the crypto provider
    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        PROV_RSA_FULL,
        CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    if (!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    while (bResult = ReadFile(hFile, rgbFile, BUFSIZE,
        &cbRead, NULL))
    {
        if (0 == cbRead)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (!CryptHashData(hHash, rgbFile, cbRead, 0))
        {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("CryptHashData failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
            CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            return dwStatus;
        }
    }

    if (!bResult)
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("ReadFile failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    cbHash = MD5LEN;
    if (CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, rgbHash, &cbHash, 0))
    {
        DWORD i;
        printf("MD5 hash of file %s is: ", filename);
        for (i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
        {
            printf("%c%c", rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4],
                rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptGetHashParam failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
    }

    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return dwStatus;
}
```

Comment: `LPCSTR filename = "c:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\filename.txt";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or copy the file to where .exe resides.